# Set Default Volume Level for Jquery Volume Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, volume

I am new to jQuery and facing difficulty in setting up initial/default volume (when the page loads up) for the slider. 
Help me in understanding where I am going wrong.

Here is a code snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#slidermusic').slider({
range: "min",
min: 1,
value: 5,
change: function(event,ui){                        
console.log("volume = "+ $('#slidermusic').slider("option","value")/100);
document.getElementById("musicplayer").volume=Number($('#slidermusic').slider("option","value"))/100;
}
```

Comment: You need to post more information then this please share whole setup in a fiddle and please share the errors you get.

Comment: I am not getting any errors as such, but upon page load the volume is set to some value which i do not want. Rather i simply want to set it at say 25 out of a max of 100. I need help in that regard. Also, this is this is the jQuery running it.